# Unable to connect SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server

I am currently running Visual Studio Web Express 2013 with SQL Server 2014 Express. Recently, I finished installing the sql server and tried to create a model by connecting the sql server. I received this message :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provide, error:40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

The time I installed I still can see the Server Name under Data Connection > Add Connection in Visual Studio but the message appeared and no database in the list shown. Later, don't know what I did, I can't even see the Server Name in the same dialog.

A list of installation here:

[image]

Does anyone know what is going on and how I can fix it?

Comment: Which OS u are using?

Comment: Window 7 ultimate.. I have update the tools  in the extension and update under tools option inside the Visual Studio 2014 express.

Comment: 1st thing to check is that if SQL Server service is running.

Comment: Yes it is running... There is SQLServer Agent which is not running and i can't make it run coz the button was disabled. The one said SQL Server , does running , Log on As under the property was Local System, I might have changed to see whether any chance of working.

Comment: I can see the Server Name but can't load the database

Comment: You need to share your connection string first.  Common issue with SQL express is users try to connect to a default instance name when in fact a named instance was installed, which is what SQL express typically installs.

Comment: Somehow don't know why the visual studio can now connecting to the database. I only make the SQL Server Agent inside Service to Automatic instead of Disable. Even I set it to Automatic, I tried to start it, it gave me error but somehow VS.net can connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to  check name of your local server. You can know that by going in sql server configuration manager n see the name of server there. [image]

See in picture name of server is `SQLEXPRESS` 
so my login is `.\[SQLEXPRESS]`

If there is no server available you need to install again.